# Is it correct of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

i want to create 16 vecotr

```
vector<int> queue[16]
```

at the same time , I want to create 3 queue in the 16 vector

so I think if i write this code like this

```
vector<int> queue[16][3]
```

this description is accurate??

I have tried. but want to check that code is basically correct?

please help me!

Comment: `vector<int> queue[16][3]` is a 2D array of 48 vectors. I don't understand what you want. If you want a queue, use `std::queue<>`.

Comment: but if i use std::queue<> , i can't read the elements in queue

Comment: That's the definition of a queue, yes: you get read access to one side (oldest) and write access to the other side (newest), aka "First In First Out" FIFO.

Comment: thx, but now I want to have priority queue.

Comment: @user3128798 there is `std::priority_queue`. As with `std::queue`, you can't see all the elements (except with some ugly trickery involving inheritance).

Comment: Then use `std::priority_queue<>`. You seem to have quite some problems in picking the right type even when C++ offers precisely what you ask for.

Comment: ok....if i want to know element in std::priority_queue, i have to write a function to check, right?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: i want to write QoS queue,therefor i have to know which element should be send first in queue. I think vector[16][3] can meet !?

Answer (score 2):

To create a `std::vector<int>` that's is initialized to a size of 16 elements, you want to say:

```
std::vector<int> queue(16);
```

The argument `16` to `queue` says to initialize the vector to have 16 elements.  Thus, that will create the vector and initialize it to hold 16 elements. You can always resize a `std::vector`, so it isn't always necessary to size it up front.

The elements will initialize to a default value based on the type.  In this case, they will initialize to 0.  If you wanted to initialize to some other value, specify it as a second argument:

```
std::vector<int> queue(16, 42);  // 16 elements with the value 42.
```

To create a 2-D vector, you need to declare a vector of vectors of ints.  This is slightly trickier.  This declares it without setting its size:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > queue;
```

To initialize this to a 16 x 3 2-D vector of vectors, the following syntax will do what you want:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > queue( 16, std::vector<int>(3) );
```

There's a bit going on there in the initialization:

- The first argument to `queue` is the size to initialize the outer vector to.  That's 16.
- The second argument is the value to initialize those elements to.  In this case, we provide a `std::vector<int>` that's been initialized to hold 3 elements.  This anonymous `vector<int>` will get *copied* to each of the 16 elements in the outer vector.

The result is a 2-D vector-of-vector-of-int whose first (outer) dimension is 16 and second (inner) dimension is 3.

Now, all that said, a 16x3 vector-of-vector-of-int is not likely to be all that efficient.  You might consider making a structure or using a `std::tuple` to bundle 3 values together, and make a vector of *that*, so you remain as a 1-D vector.

And the name of your variable `queue` suggests you're building a queue of values.  You might actually consider using `std::queue` if that suits your purposes.

Comment: i have tried 
std::vector< std::vector< int > > queue( 16, std::vector<int>(3) )
but i want use push_back() to add element

Comment: I assume you're trying to `push_back` on the outer dimension?  In that case, if the inner dimension is always 3, then you should consider using a `struct`, `class` or `std::tuple` that always has 3 elements, and make it a 1-D structure wrapping that bundle-of-3.

Comment: @user3128798: Well, you have 16 vectors, if you'd call `push_back` on `queue` you'd add a 17th vector. Stop and think. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user3128798: I have to agree with MSaiters here.  What are you trying to achieve?  This feels like an "XY Problem."  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: oh....
but i have writed code
http://ideone.com/2vZuBm

Comment: @user3128798 : And I suspect that code is very broken.  You've declared a 2-D array of 48 vectors, all independent.  The result is a 3-D structure, where the first two dimensions are fixed, and the third dimension is variable.  Somehow I don't think that's what you want, is it?  Your example pushes 4 items onto one vector out of your 48 vectors, which is why that prints 4.

Comment: @Joe Z, Yes, I just have 3 type queue in a node, and node is 16.
So... i think that vector[16][3] can do it!

Comment: @user3128798 : I'm not sure I follow your logic.  If you really want a 3-D structure, then yes, what you declared will give you a 3-D structure where the first two dimensions (16 and 3) are fixed and the third dimension is variable.  In the future, you might spend a little more time on describing the actual problem you're trying to solve in your SO question, so we're not left guessing.  We're all glad to help, but we're not mind readers.  :-)

Comment: I am so sorry for these, I hope you can understand.
My English is poor!

Comment: @user3128798 : I understand the language barrier.  We _are_ trying to help.  Programming is a discipline that requires precision, and much can get lost in translation.  Help us help you.